# display flash in joomla

Tags: flash, joomla

I am unable to display flash in Joomla.

I embedded the flash code as a custom html module.

```
<object classid="clsid:d27cdb6e-ae6d-11cf-96b8-444553540000" codebase="http://fpdownload.macromedia.com/pub/shockwave/cabs/flash/swflash.cab#version=5,0,0,0" width="468" height="60" id="banner" align="middle">

<param name="allowScriptAccess" value="sameDomain" />

<param name="movie" value="banner.swf" /><param name="quality" value="high" /><param name="bgcolor" value="#ffffff" /><embed src="banner.swf" quality="high" bgcolor="#ffffff" width="468" height="60" name="banner" align="middle" allowScriptAccess="sameDomain" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" pluginspage="http://www.macromedia.com/go/getflashplayer" />
```

Comment: Putting flash in a custom HTML module is typical and should work, you haven't given enough information to solve the problem. A link would be helpful, otherwise we'd need to see all of the code.

Answer (score 0):

Use the flash module to do this : http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/core-enhancements/flash-management/366
is very helpful module to display flash just you'll need to give the path of the flash file and set the parameters according to your need. Good luck :)